# Improving Eclipse autocompletion?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, intellisense

Currently the Eclipse autocompletion seems only to be triggered after a dot or on parameters, I want to use it for variables too, e.g. if I have

> String test="hello";

then I want the autocompletion to suggest "test" if I start typing "t" in the next line (e.g. if I intent to change the value of the variable test).

Is there any Eclipse plugin capable of doing this? I already checked the Eclipse content assist options, but seems like there no option for what I want? Thanks for any hint!

Comment: just use ctrl+space after you started typing

Comment: Thank you all guys, yes, ctrl+space indeed works. Any chance to get this functionality without pressing those keys? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First of all, thanks for all the replies. They are correct, however you have to press the key combination each time. Here's how it's done automatically:

> That plug-in is not necessary any more. Just go to
>       Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist
>   and paste:
>
> ```
> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.
> ```
>
> into the "Auto activation triggers for Java:" field.

This simply triggers auto activation after any English alphabet character and after dot.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=159157#c12
Works fine :-)

Hint: You probably want to additionally set the auto activation delay to 0, at least if you are used to visual studio ;-)

Comment: And you probably want to add there also space character, because then it completes after every space :)

Comment: This is the answer you probably want if you found this question (it's the one I wanted at least!)

Comment: It appears that in the latest version of eclipse (I'm actually using easyEclipse, which is eclipse + addons, version 1.3.1.1). You can only enter 4 characters in that field. So at most you can ask it to trigger for 'ABCD'.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the suggestions above,  did you try <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> it does incremental matching? No?

Comment: it does something when I pressed strg+space, yet I don't really understand what it does?

Comment: this is a cool feature; didn't know about it so far. I bound it to "Alt + ." to be more consistent with "Ctrl + ." for "Next". Is there an equivalent to "Previous" ("Ctrl + ,") also in this context, i.e. jump back to the previous word completion?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you press `ctrl+space` key combination, eclipse will show you the code assist window.

Type t and then hit `ctrl+space`, it will show you possible matches

Answer (score 1):

You can press "t" and then Ctrl+Space.. 
is it?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse

```
Window--->Preferences---> search for Content Assist under Content Assist go for Advanced
and check the Java Praposals.
```

done.