# eclipse Java autocompletion doesnt work

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

Hi I have a problem with Eclipse that , after i type a variable and then a '.'
the possible functions are not being autocompleted or shown as drop down.. (For example string str = "hello"; then str. should show me something like length() or substring() ) I have already tried everything with eclipse settings as seen in this link :

[Improving Eclipse autocompletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929773/improving-eclipse-autocompletion)

But it doesnt work. (Am using Java, mac ,eclipse)

Also when it shows no SWT proposals, and No default proposals, hoever if i give a space instead of '.'
 it shows some proposals ...

Any suggestions are appreciated..

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Java editor (do you get syntax coloring for example)?

Comment: yes, i get syntax coloring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>? (you may have to click space more than once)

Comment: it gives me "No default proposals.."

Comment: you can also try: Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced - explicitly check Java Proposals - Apply. Make also sure, you are in a Java Perspective, clean your project, and restart eclipse

Answer (score 1):

As your example suggests

> (For example string str = "hello"; then str.

Change it to

> (For example String str = "hello"; then str.

uppercase `S` in String, it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved by checking JavaProposals, JavaTypeProposals in ContentAssit > Advanced