# Eclipse CDT code completion/suggestion after every keypress?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

I've recently started using Eclipse CDT for a MingW project and I'm missing Visual Studio already. The code completion seems to only trigger when i press `Ctrl + Space` or after a `.`, `->`, or `::`.

I've seen a few answers that address this, however, they don't seem to hold up anymore. (Eclipse CDT doesn't even have the field mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929773/improving-eclipse-autocompletion) post.

Does anybody know how to trigger Eclipse CDT's auto-completion after each keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the latest version of CDT only has autocomplete after the `.`, `->` and `::` characters. So you cannot use the hack you mentioned.

So your best option is to use `Ctrl+Space` to trigger the autocomplete at any point.